# Referencing another a web form in another web form to pass data

Tags: c#, asp.net, cross-page-posting

I've got a page called webform1 and it has a couple of textboxes and a button and I want to pass the data to a couple of labels on webform2.

WebForm1 Button:

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnCrossPage" runat="server" Text="Button" PostBackUrl="~/Webform2.aspx" />
```

Code behind 
webform 1:

```
        public partial class webform1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

    }
    public string Name
    {
      get{ return txtName.Text;}
    }
     public string Email
    {
      get{ return txtEmai.Text;}
    }
```

Webform2 Code Behind:

```
    public partial class Webform2: System.Web.UI.Page
    { 
      Webform1 pPage = (Webform1)this.PreviousPage;
      if(pPage != null && pPage.IsCrossPagePostBack)
      {
             lblName.Text = pPage.Name;
             lblEmail.Text = pPage.Email;
      }
```

Visual Studio is not letting me reference WebForm1 in WebForm2 without a red line appearing, can anyone see a reason why?

Comment: Visual Studio is not letting me reference WebForm1 in WebForm2 without a red line, can you see a reason why?

Comment: Have you read this [Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6c3yckfw(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for once, "webForm1" is misspelled, should be "WebForm1". Also, you can ser the PreviousPageType directive:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" PreviousPageType="WebForm1" %>
```